# Declare Generic Type for class based on method parameter

Tags: java, generics, collections

My requirement is similar to below

```
public List getList(XXX xxx) {
List<xxx> list = new ArrayList<xxx>();
----some logic goes here----
return list;
}
```

I want to declare generic type of a class based on the argument passed to the method. In the above method xxx may be String or Integer or Float.

How to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `public <T> List getList(T t) {
   List<T> list  = new ArrayList<T>();
....
`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. seems like I got right answer. Let me try and confirm.

Comment: I have a doubt. What is the use of mentioning <T> before method signature. (i.e., public <T> List getList ......) Can you please clarify me ?

Comment: Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for your clarification

Comment: @Natalia: There would be no point for `T` in your code because it is only used in one place in a parameter and not in the return. It would be equivalent to `public List getList(Object t)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
    public <T> List<T> getList(T param){
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: That won't compile, unless it is in a class already with generic parameter `<T>`.

Comment: That answer is missing the usage of the `T` parameter ... shouldn't it be `ArrayList<T>();`?

Comment: @DaDaDom Not as of Java 7. `T` can be inferred in a return context. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html It is, however, missing declaration of `T`, as in `public <T> List<T> getList(T param){`

Comment: Hm, OK, true. I never thought about the typing being used from within a method to the returned type.

Comment: The complete code: public class MyList<T> {
    public List<T> getList(T param){
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList<String> list = new MyList<>();
    }
}

Comment: Shouldnt that be `public <T> List<T>` i.e. att **`<T>`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :

```
public List<Object> getList(Object object) {
  List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
  ----some logic goes here----
  return list;
}
```